# Account creation on Stack Overflow + Email verification

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, email, security

Infamous email verification process when creating an account.
Very popular method. Utilized by every user, if not all who has an email account.
A user enters an email address, clicks button, email message is delivered that contains a unique link that will help email verification of the user and new account is approved and created when the user clicks on the link. Overall, it's to help in the improvement of security of an email account and the website you are signing (to create a new user).

I've stumbled across several 'Disposable email address' or '10 minutes email' that generates temporary email address (you can also request time extension if you wish), which allows user to use that email to bypass email verification and quickly create an account (or even random account). I was wondering, does it really matter whether we use these kind of website to create an account? Or does it have to be a genuine email address? I'm sure some of you don't want to enter your real email address (perhaps security reason, etc).

Comment: I have no idea whether it's "okay" or not by SE's lights but it's not something they could stop if you wanted to do it. What I don't understand is what difference it makes? If you don't have a valid e-mail address and you're doing nothing wrong then you'll be fine. If you're spamming then your account will be deleted anyway so not having a valid e-mail address is irrelevant.

Comment: I doubt people will remind others to not use these 'Disposable email address' or '10 minutes email' thing. But thing is that they won't be able to recover if they forget their password. I know it's their responsibility but would it be too much to ask if there is some sort of 'reminder' before new users create an account? Or would this have total opposite effect?

Comment: In order to add a reminder if someone uses a service like this then you'd have to know every single one, which is impossible. At some point people have to take responsibility for their own actions; they can't expect a website to do it all for them.

Comment: Can you explain why you are asking?  Or you asking because you want to use a disposable email address and you want to know if it's OK?  In that case, in practice, it seems to be OK -- there is no explicit rule forbidding it that I'm aware of.  Or are you asking because you are worried that someone else might use a disposable email address?  If so, there is no evidence that this has been abused.  Or are you asking for some other reason?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few of these sites out there; not sure how fruitful it would be to block them all. There also are legitimate reasons for using such services (privacy, etc).

If the site starts getting spammed with these, then they probably  can blacklist these domains.